# function __get() not giving any effect in PHP

Tags: php, oop

So I'm following a tutorial about OOP in PHP and got stuck in understanding how `__get()` function works. Here's the code:

```
<?php

class Animal{

    protected $name;
    protected $favorite_food;
    protected $sound;
    protected $id;

    public static $number_of_animals = 0;
    const PI = "3.14159";

    //function to return the name
    //encapsulation
    function getName(){

        //when you want to refer attribute in a class
        return $this->name;

    }

    //initialize things
    function __construct(){

        //generate random 100-10 
        $this->id = rand(1,10);
        echo $this->id ." has been assigned<br/>";

        //akses static attribute in a class
        Animal::$number_of_animals++;

    }

    //destruct the object
    function __destruct(){

        echo $this->name ." is being destroyed :(";

    }

    //getter : to get protected attribute of a function
    function __get($name){
        echo "Asked for " . $name . "<br/>";
        return $this->$name;
    }

    //setter : set the attribute to 
    function __set($name, $value){

        switch($name){

            case "name" :
                $this->name = $value;
                break;
            case "favorite_food" :
                $this->favorite_food = $value;
                break;
            case "sound" :
                $this->sound = $value;
                break;

            default :
                echo $name ."Name not found";
        }

        echo "Set " .$name. " to " .$value. "<br/>";
    }

    function run(){
        echo $this->name. " runs<br/>";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

    function run(){
        echo $this->name. " runs like crazy<br/>";
    }   

}

$animal_one = new Animal();

$animal_one->name = " SPOT";
$animal_one->favorite_food = " MEAT";
$animal_one->sound = " RUFF";

echo $animal_one->name ." says". $animal_one->sound. " give me some " .$animal_one->favorite_food. " my id is " .$animal_one->id. " total animal is " .Animal::$number_of_animals. "<br/><br/>";

?>
```

The output will be like this :

```
5 has been assigned
Set name to SPOT
Set favorite_food to MEAT
Set sound to RUFF
Asked for name
Asked for sound
Asked for favorite_food
Asked for id
SPOT says RUFF give me some MEAT my id is 5 total animal is 1

SPOT is being destroyed :(
```

When I try to change the argument and value in `__get()` function to another attribute like `$sound` or `$favorite_food`, it doesn't give any change to the output. The output will still the same. I don't get it why we should set it only to `$name`.

Comment: What is your question? Can't work out what try to say. What isn't working? You can set values to whatever variables names you like... you're not forced to use `$name` anywhere. O_o

Comment: @JonStirling my question is, look at `__get()` (`not getName()`) function. Why we have to set `$name` in it? why not another attribute like $sound. If I change the attribute, it doesn't give any change to the output. Why? how does the `__get()` function works in my case actually?

Comment: The parameter passed into the `__get` call is the property that is trying to be accessed. The name of the variable could be anything, it will still contain the name of the property you're trying to access.

Comment: Are you actually getting confused by the `$this->$name;` line? Which you shouldn't confuse as being the same as `$this->name;`.

Comment: @JonStirling In this code, there's more than 1 property beside `$name`. I'm just confuse why in the __get() function we just called the `$name` property. Why not `$sound` property? I tried changing to `$sound` but the output is still the same as before. Sorry if I don't follow you explanation. I'm pretty new in OOP.

Comment: So, inside the `__get` method, you have a local variable `$name`. This contains a string that is the name of the property you are trying to access (e.g. if you ask for the `sound` property, then `$name` will have a value of `sound`). Now, when you get to the line `$this->$name`, `$name` gets evaluated, so `$name` gets replaced (it doesn't get replaced, but lets just say it does) with the value, `sound`. So in our example, `$this->$name` is the same as `$this->sound`. So, no matter what variable name you use for the local variable, it's the value that matters. Does that clear things up?

Comment: you must do a  __set($name, $value) before using __get($name)

Answer (score 2):

The name of the parameter inside any function is [scoped](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to that function alone, and doesn't have any reference anywhere else.

You're probably getting confused in that your local function parameter `$name` has the same name as one of it's class properties `$this->name`

Notice in your `__get` method, `$name` is a stand-in variable for what could be any protected/private property, which is dynamically evaluated at run-time:

```
$this->$name
```

as opposed to a hard-coded property

```
$this->name
```

Consider this example:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $one  = 'first';
    protected $name = 'fred';

    public function __get(String $property){
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function getOne(){
        return $this->one;
    }

    public function foo(String $variable_could_be_named_anything){
        return $variable_could_be_named_anything;
    }
}

$object = new MyClass;

echo $object->one; // first (using __get)
echo $object->getOne(); // first

$object->two = 'second'; // because this property isn't declared protected, accessed normally
echo $object->two; // second

$name = 'jon';
echo $object->name; // fred
echo $object->foo($name); // jon

echo $object->three; // PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MyClass::$three
$object->one = 'something'; // Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property
```

Comment: Note: the type declaration only works in php 7.0.0 or higher